# YOLO-NAS on Apple m1: "RuntimeError: Currently topk on mps works only for k<=16"

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

I'm trying out YOLO-NAS from supergradients on my Apple M1 pro machine. I ran the following code to inference a video on MPS:

```
from super_gradients.training import models

model = models.get("yolo_nas_s_int8", pretrained_weights="coco")
model.to("mps")
model.predict("video_path") # this causes the error below
```

and got `RuntimeError: Currently topk on mps works only for k<=16`.

I did a lot of super-gradient documentation reading, but it doesn't mention anything about MPS support. I assume it does support MPS as `model.to("mps")` did not cause any error.

Also, MPS works perfectly fine with the Yolov8 model from ultralytics.

Edit: It seems to be [a PyTorch problem](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/78915). The version of PyTorch I'm using is the latst nightly version: 2.1.0.dev20230716.

Comment: Can you add your PyTorch version to the question? Some discussion on Github says that the latest PyTorch nightly seems to solve it. https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/issues/4342

Comment: Yes sure. The version is 2.1.0.dev20230716, the latest pytorch nightly.

Comment: @OscarWan have you found Answerer for this

Comment: upgrade to latest pytorch2.x.
Also if you are running Neural Network, uplgrade trochvision too